# WCF Timeout with net.tcp service when connecting via WPF self-host

Tags: wpf, wcf

i'm looking to connect to a WCF service from w/in the same .exe from which it is hosted.  I host the service in a WPF application as:

```
        ServiceHost svc = new ServiceHost(typeof("Namespace.Service"));
        svc.Open();
```

and config file of

```
  <service name="Namespace.Service" >
    <endpoint address="Contract/tcp"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="Namespace.IContract"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

This allows me to fire up a separate VS instance, create a console app and perform the following successfully:

```
        IChannelFactory<IContract> facContract = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(new NetTcpBinding());
        IContract contract = facContract.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9002/Contract/tcp"));

        string x = contract.GetProperty; //returns value I would expect
```

However if I amend my original WPF ServiceHost code to the following, a timeout exception is thrown when I access the service (NOTE: That if I do the same thing in the Console App Service host, I do not get the timeout...):

```
        ServiceHost svc = new ServiceHost(typeof("Namespace.Service"));
        svc.Open();

        IChannelFactory<IContract> facContract = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(new NetTcpBinding());
        IContract contract = facContract.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9002/Contract/tcp"));

        string x = contract.GetProperty; //<-!!WCF Timeout exception thrown..
```

WCF Tracing doesn't provide add'l details (just confirms that a timeout exception is thrown).  Any thoughts? {this isn't a question about WCF Exception management best practices; I'm looking to access a service from within the service host & am blocked by this curious timeout exception}

EDIT:
This timeout occurs when the service host is a WPF application (perhaps others); but console app as a service host behaves as I would expect (e.g. can access a self-hosted service). I've updated the title and tags to reflect this new info...

Thanks in advance,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because WPF servicehost was hosting service on same thread as consuming service.  Problem is defined here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/74bc9d15-c458-4f1f-81a0-ebded46b68c4.  Resolution is detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752260.aspx

Resolution was to start service host **endpoint** on a separate thread ala:

```
    private void StartHostThread()
    {
        // Before opening host, add endpoints...
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContract)),
                                new NetTcpBinding(), 
                                "Contract/tcp"); //Assumes base address of net.tcp://localhost:9002/

        //For hosting on its own thread, be sure to mark service attribute 
        //  as UseSyncContext == false
        ServiceBehaviorAttribute behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
        behavior.UseSynchronizationContext = false; 

        host.Open();
    }
```

once host is opened on thread, then can consume service on main UI thread ala:

```
        EndpointAddress epoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9002/Contract/tcp");
        IContract proxy = ChannelFactory<IContract>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), epoint);
        string xyz;
        using (proxy as IDisposable)
        {
            xyz = proxy.GetProperty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your contract.GepProperty does (but it should not be a property in a first place)

This works as expected

----HOST----

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var svc = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            svc.Open();

            IChannelFactory<IService1> facContract = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new NetTcpBinding());
            var contract = facContract.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9002/Contract/tcp"));

            var x = contract.DoWork(); 
        }
```

--- Service ---

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork();
}

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "Hello Work.";
    }
}
```

--- Config ---

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="HostAndClient.Service1">
                <endpoint address="Contract/tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HostAndClient.IService1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm... strange why it not working for me then.  I did add the security node you had; w/out any luck.  FWIW the GetProperty is just a property getter (e.g. .get_GetProperty()) so don't think its anything around that.

Comment: Well - looks like this works with a console app as a service host; but doesn't work with WPF app's as service host (perhaps others).  I'll update my original post to be more specific.